# FragmentDialog with background scrim

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I want to use

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_NoActionBar);
        }
```

But I want to still have the dark background scrim. How do I achieve that? I suppose I can create a child Theme but I don’t know how I would do that to specifically get the scrim. Thanks.

BTY here is onStart

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
```

Here is my attempt but I cannot find the parent. Android cannot find `Theme.Holo...`

```
<style name="WithScrim" parent="Theme.Holo.">

</style>
```

Comment: If you theme the dialog with `Theme.Holo` won't it be full screen (so nothing to scrim)? It's `parent="android:Theme.Something"`. Why can't you use `Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog`?

Comment: You have the right idea. I solved it and forgot to report I used `<style name="MyScrimTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">`. Thank you very much. Will you please post as a response so I may mark this thread for the benefit of future seekers?